# Creating arrow-sourcable table rows in Draw.io

Tags: graphics, diagram, entity-relationship, draw.io

I'm trying to create a three column table in draw.io. I've started with the software / entity relationship example and adapted the style slightly. I've taken this example because I need my arrows to originate and go to specific rows in the table, and not just the table in general.

[image]

However, I have a few problems, I'm at a loss on how to create a third column, I would like for the vertical line to extend all the way down even if the elements don't (currently they are a right-line on the left inside element of the "row"). And finally, I need to be able to adapt the size of the columns flexibly (rather than having to edit settings in the individual rows). Am I missing a better solution here?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I Understood all details, but this article might help:
https://drawio-app.com/tables-in-drawio-got-a-makeover/

You can make something like this and modify it additionally.

[image]

or just copy/paste this code to Extras > Edit diagram

```
<mxGraphModel dx="2062" dy="762" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="850" pageHeight="1100" math="0" shadow="0">
  <root>
    <mxCell id="0" />
    <mxCell id="1" parent="0" />
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-53" value="Table" style="shape=table;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;startSize=30;container=1;collapsible=0;childLayout=tableLayout;" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry x="450" y="270" width="180" height="150" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-54" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;collapsible=0;dropTarget=0;pointerEvents=0;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;points=[[0,0.5],[1,0.5]];portConstraint=eastwest;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-53">
      <mxGeometry y="30" width="180" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-55" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;connectable=0;overflow=hidden;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-54">
      <mxGeometry width="60" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-56" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;connectable=0;overflow=hidden;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-54">
      <mxGeometry x="60" width="60" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-57" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;connectable=0;overflow=hidden;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-54">
      <mxGeometry x="120" width="60" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-58" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;collapsible=0;dropTarget=0;pointerEvents=0;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;points=[[0,0.5],[1,0.5]];portConstraint=eastwest;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-53">
      <mxGeometry y="70" width="180" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-59" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;connectable=0;overflow=hidden;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-58">
      <mxGeometry width="60" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-60" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;connectable=0;overflow=hidden;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-58">
      <mxGeometry x="60" width="60" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-61" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;connectable=0;overflow=hidden;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-58">
      <mxGeometry x="120" width="60" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-62" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;collapsible=0;dropTarget=0;pointerEvents=0;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;points=[[0,0.5],[1,0.5]];portConstraint=eastwest;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-53">
      <mxGeometry y="110" width="180" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-63" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;connectable=0;overflow=hidden;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-62">
      <mxGeometry width="60" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-64" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;connectable=0;overflow=hidden;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-62">
      <mxGeometry x="60" width="60" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-65" value="" style="shape=partialRectangle;html=1;whiteSpace=wrap;connectable=0;overflow=hidden;fillColor=none;top=0;left=0;bottom=0;right=0;" vertex="1" parent="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-62">
      <mxGeometry x="120" width="60" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-69" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=1;exitY=0.5;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;" edge="1" parent="1" source="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-66" target="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-54">
      <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-66" value="" style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry x="120" y="200" width="120" height="60" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-70" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=1;exitY=0.5;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;" edge="1" parent="1" source="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-67" target="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-58">
      <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-67" value="" style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry x="120" y="330" width="120" height="60" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-71" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=1;exitY=0.5;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;" edge="1" parent="1" source="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-68" target="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-62">
      <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="ppajL3H83U300mlp604u-68" value="" style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry x="120" y="470" width="120" height="60" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
  </root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

Regards,